# How come eclipse doesn't find my intent

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-manifest

How come eclipse doesn't find my intent...

```
Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.project.MyProj.MenuActivity");

                    startActivity(menuIntent);
```

if it is clearly declered in manifest ??

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.project.MyProj.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.project.MyProj.MenuActivity"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
```

In Debugger I get the error: Source not found

Comment: See here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent, how to start new Activity

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);` (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) ?

Comment: i get an eror that constructor is undefined

Comment: if MenuActivity is not your launch activity, try to remove the intent-filter tag in your manifest

Comment: maybe that is because of my eclipse??

Answer (score 0):

I know what was wrong, it happened, but I don't know why exactly it happened. In my `MenuActivity` I was writing a method `onCreateOptionsMenu`. and if something goes wrong there then I get this error.